# input a file of words and numbers into an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input

Okay, I am not very experienced with programming, but I have an assignment to create a c++ program that uses numerical methods to calculate the temperature of a mixture of three substances, based on the enthalpy and percent of each substance in the mixture. its basically a polynomial of h = a1*T + a2*T^2 + ... up to a6. These coefficents a1 through a6 are given in a table, for each of H20, H2, and O2. My program needs to be able to read the substance names and the values of the coefficients from a .dat file so that I can use the coefficients for my equations. That's what I need help with. How can I get the program to input the substance names and coefficient values into an array so I can use them in my equations? Sorry for the novel but I tried to give as much context as possible.
below is exactly what is in my .dat file, and what I am trying to put in an array. The substance name is first, followed by a1, a2, etc.

```
H2O 406598.40  440.77751  -.12006604       .000015305539    -.00000000072544769   -4475789700

H2  50815.714  9.9343506  -.000027849704  -.00000035332966   .000000000041898079  -14329128

O2  961091.64  199.15972  -.052736240      .00000897950410  -.00000000063609681   -318699310
```

this is my source code so far, but its not working, and I'm pretty lost.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double myArray[21];

ifstream file("thermo2.dat");

if (file.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
    {
            file >> myArray[i];
    }
}
else 
{
    cout << "the file did not open";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
    {
        cout << "      " << myArray[i];
    }

return 0;
}
```

thanks!

EDIT: started trying to work with an array of structs....I keep getting an error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, double&, char)'. heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    string species;
    double a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
};

int main()
{
ifstream fin;

fin.open("thermo2.dat");

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Failed to open file" << endl;
}


Data * database = new Data[3];
string line;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{


    getline(fin, database[i].species, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a1, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a2, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a3, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a4, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a5, '\t');
    getline(fin, database[i].a6, '\t');
}


system("pause");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: First decide how you want to store the data. Do you want one array or three? Do you need the substance names from the file? If so, how do you want to store *them?*

Comment: I'm trying to use one array of structures, but I struggling to get it to work, if you could take a look at the edit I posted and provide any insight that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your structure as:

```
struct Data
{
    string species;
    double a[6];
}
```

And read as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 fin >> database[i].species;
 for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
   fin >> database[i].a[j];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Create a `struct` to hold the data for each material.

   ```
   struct Material
   {
      std::string name;
      double coeffcients[6];
   };
   ```
2. Create a function to read one `Material` from a stream.

   ```
   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Material& mat)
   {
       // Read the name.
       in >> mat.name;

       // If there was an error, return.
       // Let the calling function deal with errors.
       if (!in)
       {
          return in;
       }

       // Read the coefficients.
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
       {
           in >> mat.coefficients[i];
           if (!in)
           {
              return in;
           }
       }
       return in;
   };
   ```
3. In the `main` function, write the driving code.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       // Create a vector of materials.
       std::vector<Material> materials;

       // Open the input file.
       ifstream file("thermo2.dat");

       // Read Materials the file in a loop and
       // add them to the vector.
       Material mat;
       while (file >> mat)
       {
          materials.push_back(mat);
       }

       // Now use the vector of Materials anyway you like.


       // Done with main.
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Before I realized you had replied, I was trying to make it work with a structure. Is there any way I can make it work this way? I keep getting an error with all the getlines for a1 - a6. Ill post my current code as an edit

Comment: `getline` can't be used to read a `double`. Use `operator>>` for that.